# I am adding an Image in UIImageView but it does not display

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am adding an Image in UIImageView but it does not display

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y:20, width: 100, height: 100))
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "sample.jpg")
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift display image UIImageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193132/swift-display-image-uiimageview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: Go to `Assets.xcassets` in your project. then create `New Image Set` with name sample. after that drag and drop `sample.jpg` into `sample` image set

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y:20, width: 100, height: 100))
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "sample") // then use this
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Works Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

When you use
`UIImage(named: "sample.jpg")`
then Xcode expects the string to be a valid asset catalog name, so you will need to create an asset for your image, like
`UIImage(named: "mysample")`.

See here: http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7

Answer (score 0):

Remove the format on the filename and you should be good to go, so do:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y:20, width: 100, height: 100))
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "sample")
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Let me know if it's working now for you.